# Can I draw ER diagrams?

Tags: support

Is there a way to draw [ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) diagrams? or the only way is to upload a screen shot or some picture?

something like this more or less:

> [image]

---

Maybe  something like:

```
    _________               ______
   | Account |------------ | Item | 
   ----------               ------- 
      |
      |
      |
   _________
  | bla bla |
   ---------
```

but how can I draw the circles? or rhombus?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Database Administrators does not support lines or shapes of any kind suitable for building diagrams. The way you have done it in your meta question, composing a diagram elsewhere, uploading its image to an image hosting service and linking to the picture in your post, appears to be the only option so far.

Comment: Isn't ASCII art another option?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: For a true artist, it always is!